# Joomla! 1.5.9 changing page titles on menu

Tags: joomla, menu, title

I am working in Joomla! 1.5.9 and trying to change the names to the page titles in the menu browser (I think that's what it's called).

I have only been able to find basic page info on those specific pages on the "sections manager/green folder" within the editor/admin site. However, all title changes I make to those pages within are not reflected on the actual web site itself.

I have been able to "add" a section (just out of curiosity) but it is not visible on the actual site itself. Nor can I figure out how to delete any of the pages/sections.

I don't know where to find access to the editing page title options.

Comment: Just to clarify which "page title" you are referring to... The text on the _menu_ should be on the relevant menu, found in the Menu Manager? Or are you referring to the `title` element? Or some other on page title text?

Answer (score 3):

You can specify page titles in "Parameters (System)" in  the menu item.

Joomla 1.5.9 is very old now and you should at least update to Joomla 1.5.26 and install applicable [Security hotfixes for Joomla EOL versions](https://docs.joomla.org/Security_hotfixes_for_Joomla_EOL_versions).

Ideally you should be thinking about migrating to Joomla 2.5 or Joomla 3.2.

Comment: +1 for suggesting upgrading. Using such an old version really isn't any good - it's only a matter of time until you'll be hacked.